# Create normally distributed columns, with different mean values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following numpy matrix:

```
R = np.matrix(np.ones([3,3]))

# Update R matrix based on sales statistics
for i in range(0, len(R)):
    for j in range(0, len(R)):  
        R[j,i] = scipy.stats.norm(2, 1).pdf(i) * 100  

print(R)

[[ 5.39909665 24.19707245 39.89422804]
 [ 5.39909665 24.19707245 39.89422804]
 [ 5.39909665 24.19707245 39.89422804]]
```

I would like to convert **each** column, **multiplying** the index (0,1,2) to the corresponding **density value** of the normal distribution, with mean equals to, specifically, 5.39909665 for the first column, 24.19707245 the second and 39.8942280 the third; and standard deviation equals to 1.

Ultimately, creating a matrix as:

```
[norm(5.39, 1).pdf(0), norm(24.197, 1).pdf(0), ...]
     [ norm(5.39, 1).pdf(1), norm(24.197, 1).pdf(1), ...]
     [ norm(5.39, 1).pdf(2), norm(24.197, 1).pdf(2), ...]]
```

How can I create the final matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The `pdf` method works much like any numpy function, in the sense you can input arrays with same shapes in combinations with scalars. You can create R with something like:

```
ix = np.repeat(np.arange(3),3).reshape((3,3)) #row index, or ix.T for column index
R = scipy.stats.norm(2,1).pdf(ix.T)*100
>>array([[ 5.39909665, 24.19707245, 39.89422804],
   [ 5.39909665, 24.19707245, 39.89422804],
   [ 5.39909665, 24.19707245, 39.89422804]])
```

Following the same logic, if you want your [i,j] index to be `scipy.stats.norm(scipy.stats.norm(2,1).pdf(j) * 100, 1).pdf(i)` (as from the matrix you put as result), use:

```
scipy.stats.norm(scipy.stats.norm(2,1).pdf(ix.T) * 100, 1).pdf(ix)
```

Comment: No; basically, I would like to create a Gaussian distribution for each column, with mean given by the Value that is repeated in the original matrix R, evaluated at each step [0,1,2]

Comment: check now, the values are the same as your result matrix, although they seem odd. However once you understand how to put matrices as arguments for `pdf` you can work this on your own for any case.

Comment: the issue with that is that it uses the same values across each column; instead, I would expect that pdf evaluated at 0 is different from the one evaluated at 1 and 2; and this should happen for each row, in each column. Ultimately, the matrix should contain 9 different values from three different Gaussians with means, respectively, equal to [ 5.39909665 24.19707245 39.89422804]